# Using Mutators (or set methods) inside Constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, mutators

I was just wondering if using mutators inside constructors were bad practice or if it were one of those "personal preference" just like how some people prefer `foo->bar` over `(*foo).bar`.

Example:

```
public Triangle() { 
    this.side1 = 0;
    this.side2 = 0;
    this.side3 = 0;
}
```

Or

```
public Triangle() { 
    setSide1(0); 
    setSide2(0); 
    setSide3(0);
 }
```

**Edit**:
This is for when I'm designing a class called `Triangle`. 
I'm still learning Java and I am in the topic for default constructors. So with the answer's I'm getting so far, it's better to initalize the variable.

```
public class Triangle {
    private double side1 = 0;
    private double side2 = 0;
    private double side3 = 0;

public Triangle() {}
}
```

Comment: Depends. For example if the logic is complicated I'd create a new method, just for the sake of readability.

Comment: I would do neither. I would initialize those fields at their declaration point. And because 0 is the default value for integral types, I would not initialize them at all.

Comment: Besides that, this question - as it is - is opinion-based. Maybe you could describe a more specific situation, so that this question gets answerable ...

Comment: If the setters are overridable, calling them from the constructor would be a bad idea, as a potentially overridden method would be called before the fields of the subclass are initialized. I would first ask myself: shouldn't the class be immutable? Does it really need setters?

Comment: Thank you gentlemen for the quick response!

Comment: I've never really used setters inside constructors by the way. While browsing I've read some peoples codes with setters inside their constructors and I thought they were okay to use. I wanted to double check if it were a bad idea, which most of you have said isn't a good idea to do. Thank again everyone.

Comment: Just as a hint: Your edited class can/should be shortened to: `public class Triangle { private double side1; private double side2; private double side3; }`. First of all, the default value for the double type is 0.0; there is no point in setting it explicitely. Java does this for you. A parameterless constructor with no statemens is automatically added to the class by the compiler, if you have no other constructor. So it can be ommitted, too.